# Swift: When we made an extension to Int, what's the "self" within a property getter supposed to be?

Tags: ios, swift, swift-extensions

**It seems that it's a bug and resolved in Xcode 7 with Swift(2b3)**

To make convenient observation, let's post the code to playground, the result will be indicated by the comments.

```
extension Int {
    var sq: Int {
        mutating get {
            self                       //5
            self = self * self         //25
            return self                //25    Here 25 is made
        }
    }
}

var n: Int = 5                         //5
n.sq                                   //25
n                                      //5      Why isn't 25?
```

My question is, if `self` within the getter of property `sq` is referring to the integer itself, why `n` keeps 5 after `n.sq` did?

Let's see what happen if we just add a setter:

```
extension Int {
    var sq: Int {
        mutating get {
            self                       //5
            self = self * self         //25
            return self                //25    Here 25 is made
        }

        //It's not making any sense, just for testing what's self referring to
        set {
        }
    }
}

var n: Int = 5                         //5
n.sq                                   //25
n                                      //25     It's just what we want!
```

So, what's the problem in the case upper?

**BTW, in this case, implement a func like `sq()` will be more reasonable and it's proved, but I just want to know why it does not work within the property getter.**

Comment: Since Int is a value type it will always be a copy. So infact i wonder myself what the use case could be for a mutating get and a value type other than you spare () while using it.

Comment: @Alex Thank you for your reminding, but I still want to know why it does not work within the property getter.

Comment: Please try again in Xcode 7. This appears to be a resolved bug. In Swift2b3 it behaves as you suggest.

Comment: Well, obviously it's a bug since adding setter definitely shouldn't change the behavior of the getter. I guess it's a problem with a mutating variable that is readonly (it only has the getter).

Comment: @RobNapier Yes I am using Xcode 7, thank you for your response, what a incredible reputation! @0@

Comment: Are you on the latest (beta3)? In 6.3, I see the behavior you indicated, but in 7beta3, I get 25 at the end, without set().

Answer (score 0):

A couple solutions:

Change the line `n.sq` to `n = n.sq` since the get method returns a value based on self and doesn't really mutate it.

If you want to just use a method in the way you currently are, write it within the extension like this:

```
mutating func sq() {
    self = self * self
}
```

Then you can call  `n.sq()` and it will do what you're wanting

Comment: Hello, Rachel. Thanks for your prompt response. A func will be fine and reasonable. But with the same code "self = self * self", I just want to know what's the different between func and property getter, why the self within the property getter does difference.

Comment: Well, like I said, a getter returns a value, like a whole new Int (a copy, in your case, squared), rather than mutating the one given, even if you specify `self = self * self`, it's just how the method works. It changes within the setter because a setter mutates the value by its very nature. @ShaowenSu

Comment: I don't think so. First of all, if we remove the code within the setter, the case bottom still works. Secondly, we make the 'self = self * self; return self' to 'self = 123; return 456 //for example', the case bottom exactly shows n is 123. So,  it does change self.

Comment: Well, it's not supposed to, I copied your code to mess around with, and mine just crashes without any changes, sorry I don't think I quite understand what you're looking for here @ShaowenSu